# React: Decrease action causes undefined state in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, bind

I am using Redux to implement a basic Like counter in this project / Example

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mralwin/Reduxstagram

This is the following code used to manage the likes states increase:

**Action**

```
export function increment(index) {
  return {
    type: "INCREMENT_LIKES",
    index
  };
}
```

**Reducer**

```
function posts(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INCREMENT_LIKES":
      const i = action.index;
      return [
        ...state.slice(0, i), // before the one we are updating
        { ...state[i], likes: state[i].likes + 1 },
        ...state.slice(i + 1) // after the one we are updating
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
<button onClick={this.props.increment.bind(null, i)} className="likes">
```

Now i want to add as exercise a *decrease function* to manage the *decrease state likes*, and here where the issue comes from.

See the code:

**Action**

```
export function decrease(index) {
  return {
    type: 'DECREASE_LIKES',
    index: i
  };
}
```

**Reducer** => Added **DECREASE_LIKES** case

```
function rooms(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_LIKES' :
      const i = action.index;
      return [
        ...state.slice(0, i),
        {...state[i], likes: state[i].likes + 1 },
        ...state.slice(i + 1)
      ];
    case 'DECREASE_LIKES' :
      return [
        ...state.slice(0, i),
        {...state[i], likes: state[i].likes - 1 },
        ...state.slice(i + 1)
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
<button onClick={this.props.decrease.bind(null, i)} className="likes">
```

While I am debugging it looks like that in the **DECREASE** case the *state* is undefined.

What am i doing wrong? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the variable `i` is not defined in scope of the `DECREASE_LIKES` case of your reducers switch statement. This will therefore cause the logic of the `DECREASE_LIKES` reduction to producue incorrect results.

Consider making the following adjustments to your reducer to resolve the issue:

```js
function rooms(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT_LIKES' : {
      const i = action.index;
      return [
        ...state.slice(0, i),
        {...state[i], likes: state[i].likes + 1 },
        ...state.slice(i + 1)
      ];
    }
    case 'DECREASE_LIKES' : {
      // Use a different variable for visual distinction/clarity
      const j = action.index;

      // Use j from action index in reduction logic for this action
      return [
        ...state.slice(0, j),
        {...state[j], likes: state[j].likes - 1 },
        ...state.slice(j + 1)
      ];
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```